# SDCAlertView and UIViewController with UIButton

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer, sdcalertview

I have to display a custom iOS 7-style alert requester with a set of custom buttons (category filter toggles to be specific) in the center. For this, I've found the excellent [SDCAlertView](https://github.com/Scott90/SDCAlertView) on GitHub. My approach is to create a custom `UIViewController`, which handles the creation of buttons and the button touches, instantiate it, then insert into the alert's `contentView` like this:

```
SDCAlertView *alert = [[SDCAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Filter"
                                                  message:nil
                                                 delegate:self
                                        cancelButtonTitle:@"Clear"
                                        otherButtonTitles:@"Filter", nil];

GKSecondViewController *vc = [[GKSecondViewController alloc] init];
UIView *view = vc.view;
[alert.contentView addSubview:view];
[view sdc_centerInSuperview];

[alert.contentView sdc_pinHeight:100];
[alert.contentView sdc_pinWidth:100];
[alert.contentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];

[alert show];
```

My view controller (`GKSecondViewController`) looks like this:

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
        [self.view setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

        [self.view sdc_pinHeight:100];
        [self.view sdc_pinWidth:100];

        UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] init];
        [button setTitle:@"Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button addGestureRecognizer:[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tap:)]];
        [button setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];

        [button sdc_pinHeight:100];
        [button sdc_pinWidth:100];

        [self.view addSubview:button];

        [button sdc_centerInSuperview];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)tap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    gesture.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}
```

(You may need [SDCAutoLayout](https://github.com/Scott90/SDCAutoLayout) too.) When I click on the button in the alert, it crashes with no hints in the tracelog. What do I miss or do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can take a view controller's view and add it to some other view hierarchy.

In your case, I would not use `GKSecondViewController`. I would create the buttons in the view controller of your object, and use target/action to talk back to the same view controller. If you must use `GKSecondViewController`, `SDCAlertView` would have to support view controller containment, which it doesn't at this point.